# rails asset pipeline production precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, precompile

I have a directory `projName/vendor/assets/bootstrap/css/`
I am in production mode.
production.rb contains: config.assets.precompile `<< /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/`
when I run rake assets:precompile 
I get 
`projName/public/assets/css/`  but I want `projName/public/assets/bootstrap/css/`
I do not understand why the bootstrap directory is not there.
Actually  all the top level directories under vendor/assets and app/assets are missing in `public assets/`

Comment: What exactly were you hoping to match with that Regex?

Comment: Are you trying to get twitter bootstrap included in your css. If so just add `@import "bootstrap";` at top of the scss file your views are using.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled assets are written to the location specified in `config.assets.prefix`. By default, this is the `public/assets` directory.

To understand this you have to first understand what precompiling is and does. Let me explain

When you run (a rake task)

```
rake assets:precompile
```

it will create a `public` folder inside your application folder which will compile all your asset manifests (ie. your `application.css` and `application.js`)

How exactly does this happen ?? -> Rails comes bundled with a rake task which will compile all this. That rake task is what is shown above.

Compiled assets are written to the location specified in `config.assets.prefix`. By default, this is the `public/assets` directory.

The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js, application.css and all non-JS/CSS files (this will include all image assets automatically) from app/assets folders including your gems.

And thats exactly what that regex means (to include everything in your app/assets folder), you can also explicitly provide it as shown in the answer above.

Hope this helped.

Here are few links for your reference

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

http://dennisreimann.de/blog/precompiling-rails-assets-for-development/

Answer (score 0):

What does that regex mean? If you want to precompile everything, try this.

```
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']
```

Comment: Does this include coffee, sass, sccs, slim, haml etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to precompile everything, try this:

```
def precompile?(path)
  %w(app lib vendor).each do |asset_root|
    assets_path = Rails.root.join(asset_root, 'assets').to_path
    return true if path.starts_with?(assets_path)
  end
  false
end

# Precompile all assets under app/assets (unless they start with _)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << proc do |name, path|
  starts_with_underscore = name.split('/').last.starts_with?('_')
  unless starts_with_underscore
    path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(name).to_path unless path # Rails 4 passes path; Rails 3 doesn't
    precompile?(path)
  end
end
```

(Based on the [code in the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets).)